# VB.NET Data Adapter Fill is taking an abnormally long time

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, network-protocols, antivirus, sqldataadapter

I have a stored procedure which used to take 24seconds to run. I changed the way the stored procedure retrieves the data, and using the exact same source data it now it takes 18seconds when running it from the MSSQL Management Studio.

The VB.NET form that displays it used to take around 25seconds to load. It now takes 2 and a half minutes. The VB.NET code that retrieves the data has not been altered.

I cannot understand how this is possible, as the StoPro returns the exact same data (including the column names). The only thing I suspect might be the issue is that we recently changed the antivirus software. Please note that this change to the StoPro was done before the antivirus switch, but the excessive form load time has only been identified recently.

I have seen a similar thread, but I am not using a VM, and changing network settings is near to impossible due to policy restrictions.
[SqlDataAdapter.Fill suddenly taking a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992560/sqldataadapter-fill-suddenly-taking-a-long-time)

Any suggestions?

Comment: search for "parameter sniffing" and "cached query plan"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465003/sql-server-slow-results-with-parameters

Comment: Thank you so much Mitch Wheat, it worked. After applying the following code at the start of the StoPro, the software displayed the results in 20 seconds:
SET ARITHABORT ON